# Is there a way to make `endpoint.initiate()` always throw on failed request?

Tags: error-handling, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I dispatch a [RTKQuery mutation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/mutations) inside a custom thunk like this:

```js
const result = await dispatch(
  commentsApi.endpoints.myEndpoint.initiate(params)
)
```

and I noticed that when the underlying request fails, this does not throw an exception - the above `dispatch` call `resolves` into an object with an `error` property instead.

What is the reason for that? I would prefer `rejecting`, so I could use it like this:

```js
try {
  await dispatch(commentsApi.endpoints.myEndpoint.initiate(params))
  someOtherCallDependentOnMutationSuccess()
} catch (e) {
  // ...
}
```

Is there a way to make all `endpoint.initiate()` calls reject when the underlying request fails? Or is there a good reason not to want that?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the logic to make the `dispatch` throw an error using [`.unwrap()`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#unwrapping-result-actions):

```js
try {
  await dispatch(commentsApi.endpoints.myEndpoint.initiate(params)).unwrap()
  // following code will be reached only if previous dispatch succeded
  someOtherCallDependentOnMutationSuccess()
} catch (e) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: This works, nice :) Still not what I was ideally hoping for though - I would love for the `initiate()` to reject/unwrap by default, without having to specify it, so I (and more importantly my colleagues who have never seem this thread) don't have to know and remember to unwrap manually like this. But if that is not possible, I will go with this approach you gave me and link this answer in a code-comment :)

Comment: I think the logic and responsability is enterely at the `dispatch`, so `initiate` function doesnt have much to do here. But Im not sure at 100% honestly.